# How can I change plugin to give access to editor user role?

Tags: plugins, user-roles, user-access

I want to give my editors access to a settings page to a plugin I've installed on their website. As of now, it's only visible to Administrators.

The plugin I'm using is uTubeVideo Gallery, and there is no option to give users other than administrators access.

In his admin.php I found these lines, which I know creates the settings page:

```
public function addMenus()
{
    add_menu_page('uTubeVideo', 'uTubeVideo', 'manage_options', 'utubevideo_settings', array($this, 'option_panel'), plugins_url('utubevideo-gallery/i/utubevideo_icon_16x16.png'));
    add_submenu_page('utubevideo_settings', 'uTubeVideo Galleries', __('Galleries', 'utvg'), 'manage_options', 'utubevideo_settings_galleries', array($this, 'gallery_panel')); 
}
```

Is there a way for me to tweak his code so I can give access to editors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `manage_options` argument you see in both function calls is a capability. That particular capability makes the page accessible [only to administrators](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Administrator).

To make this work, you could change that to [one of the editor capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor) like `edit_others_posts` You could also [create a new capability](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) and use that.

However, doing either will mean hacking the plugin and the next time the plugin is updated your changes will be overwritten, which is why hacking plugins is generally a bad idea

I would:

1. Think carefully about why editors need access to this *global*
   settings page. "Editors" are logically a "content" role, not a
   "global site administration" role, which is what you seem to be
   partially converting them to.
2. Consider whether what editors need is perhaps a shortcode or other
   simplified access to the plugin functionality.
3. If neither #1 nor #2 fit, contact the plugin author and find out why access is
   limited and whether the author would be willing to change the plugin
   code

Comment: Thanks for a great answer :) I will probably change the code to the plugin, and update the code each time it get's updated. Mainly because it's an essential part of the site. The page is actually just a library for the video gallery with options to add youtube links and edit gallery items, so I don't see the point in not being able to give them access.

Comment: Then you really ought to contact the plugin author.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
public function addMenus()
{
   add_menu_page('uTubeVideo', 'uTubeVideo', 'delete_posts', 'utubevideo_settings', array($this, 'option_panel'), plugins_url('utubevideo-gallery/i/utubevideo_icon_16x16.png'));
   add_submenu_page('utubevideo_settings', 'uTubeVideo Galleries', __('Galleries', 'utvg'), 'delete_posts', 'utubevideo_settings_galleries', array($this, 'gallery_panel')); 
}
```

Comment: using delete posts authors can also access it besides editor.

Comment: Contributors could access it as well

Comment: so you need to install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/screenshots/

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?